# login page check user from 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site which has two types of users that are stored in two different tables one is saved as a user and the other one as a business in the user table its columns are as follow:

```
first_name, last_name, user_email,user_pws
```

And the business columns is as follow:

```
business_name, business_email,business_pws
```

I want to make a PHP coded login page that if the user enters email and password the login system will check which one the user is. how can I do this? my current code is a simple login form.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: yes I know that's why all my passwords are stored with PHP password_hash() and I make sure my code is not sql_injectable by using MySQLi prepared statements don't worry I take all the security precautions

Comment: and will continue to improve my security system in my code as it one of my biggest concerns about code

Comment: Unless this is purely for academic purposes, don't write your own login system. This is a solved problem and community-based solutions provide a degree of security you won't have on your own. Writing a login system that "works" is easy. Writing one that's actually secure is really hard. It's not worth the risk.

Comment: are you currently able to login with both users? and just want to check the type of the logged user?

Comment: This schema seems to make solving your problem a lot harder than it should be. Create two entries, not one entry with two login "options".

Comment: well why not if I make sure I follow all the security steps I surely can do it for a commercial website.

Comment: Do you even know how many steps there are? There's [thousands](https://owasp.org/www-project-cheat-sheets/). If you want your users to end up on [sites like this](https://haveibeenpwned.com) then code you bash together yourself is the way to go.

Comment: i understand but the business and users both have more columns and i need the tables to be separate

Comment: Separate your *identity* from *authorization*.

Comment: yes i know and i might use laravel but for now i am doing alone

Comment: @Furquan i am only able to login with one table and thats the user table i want to be able to query both tables

Comment: If you base this on Laravel's authentication mechanism then you're on a solid foundation. The key here: If/when there's a vulnerability discovered in Laravel you'll have a chance to respond and apply a patch before you're attacked. If there's a bug in your own homebrew code you will by definition be attacked first, and will not only have to plug the hole yourself, but figure out how much damage has been done. This is how business fail and careers get destroyed.

Comment: @tadmanat agreed i will look into laravel

Comment: @Furquan will it be better if i use javascript instead of php????

Comment: @FrancoBoshoff It totally depends on the need, If you are thinking server-side javascript, then you must be proficient in nodeJs like techs. The problem here is not the language, it's the approach that you are taking, In my suggestion either stick with PHP standards or choose any good framework and don't invent the wheels(If not needed).

Comment: I agree but the problem is I 100% don't know how php framework works so I might use node js cuz I need a server side language.

Comment: @Furquan I almost built my entire website around 10 pages of php i will have trouble as i don't understand how framework works so

Comment: @Furquan if I continue with my php login system without a framework!!! And I post it in stackoverflow and tag you will you check it out at tell me where the security problem are?

Comment: @FrancoBoshoff, Sure, I will try as much as I can. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MAY LEAD TO SECURITY RISKS**

*this was just for what the user here was asking*

It's a little weird because you have to make sure that emails are unique keys however making them a unique key in each table would still mean someone could make one in each table. I'm not sure if that's what you're getting at and I guess to counteract that you could have a table of used emails....

But to get to your question, IF the emails do not overlap between tables I imagine some SQL statement such as:
`select users.user_email, business.business_email from users,business where users.user_email='foo' or business.business_email='foo';`. I'm not too great with SQL yet either but you can mess around with something like this and I'm sure it'll get you on the right track.

Comment: Not sure this really helps as this could open up the system to a whole host of severe security issues.

Comment: @tadman can i ask so you are good with php security ?

Comment: @tadman I'm assuming he's doing this for a class assignment, since I'm currently also in a full stack class which has us do this kind of stuff. I don't think the professor is expecting the site to be bullet proof but just would like to see effort of implementation.

Comment: @nickgior We can't presume this is just for an assignment, nor can we presume that other people who see this answer are. This is how sites end up being compromised: People embrace solutions like this without understanding the ramifications and consequences.

Comment: no no I am making a web site, not for a class I am a self-learned dev but i see that i make security mistakes sometimes

Comment: @FrancoBoshoff building its own login system is not prohibited in PHP, But definitely, you will have to be cautious, as you are already using two tables, it's definitely going to be more headache

Comment: Security is not a PHP thing, but in PHP you must be *extra vigilant* since large parts of the PHP community do not take it nearly as seriously as it should. When writing a public-facing web application that has real-world users you *must* pay close attention to security. There are too many tools out there that will crack your site in an instant if you let your guard down.

Comment: @tadman fair point. I'll put a warning disclaimer in what I had posted.

Comment: i would like your help with my site

Comment: I can't provide 1:1 support like that, but consider services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io) where you can engage with professionals on an as-needed basis.